# I want to insert one item from specified row, to another table

Tags: mysql

So I have these 2 tables. I need to get whatever is in the 1st row, 3rd column of Table 1 (in this case, ducks) and insert it into Table 2, 1st row, 6th column (marked [here])

```
       table 1 (teams)
  PK
team_id   groupno   tname   oname   onumber   oemail   group   series
   1         1      ducks   laura    123      a@b.com    A       1
   2         2      birds   john     456      c@d.com    A       1     
   3         3      redds   hanna    789      e@f.com    A       1
   4         4      blues   mark     102      g@h.com    A       1
```

team_id and groupno while look the same, groupno goes up to 10 (counting all teams in a group), team_id goes on

```
       table 2 (games)
  PK
game_id   match_id   time   field   group   team1   team2   series
  1           1      0900     1       A     [here]   N/A      1
  2           2      0930     1       A      N/A     N/A      1
  3           3      1000     1       A      N/A     N/A      1
  4           4      1030     1       A      N/A     N/A      1
```

game_id and match_id arent's the same, math_id goes up to 36 (It counts all the games played in single series), game_id goes on

Below what I've been working with

```
UPDATE games INNER JOIN teams
       ON games.game_id = 1
       SET games.team2 = teams.tname
       WHERE teams.series=1;
```

What I want the result to be

Example:

1. vs 2. --- 3. vs 4.
2. vs 3. --- 2. vs 4.
3. vs 4. --- 2. vs 3.

It should take the names from table 1 and arranges them into game slots so each team plays against each other

```
 PK
game_id   match_id   time   field   group   team1   team2   series
  1           1      0900     1       A     ducks   birds     1
  2           2      0930     1       A     reds    blues     1
  3           3      1000     1       A     ducks   reds      1
  4           4      1030     1       A     birds   blues     1
  5           5      1100     1       A     ducks   blues     1
  6           6      1130     1       A     reds    birds     1
```

Comment: 'WHERE table1.category=1;' - tricky there isn't a category in table1?

Comment: Please share all the fields in table1 and table2

Comment: what is the relationship between these tables? "3rd row of Table 1 " and "Table 2, 1st row, 4th column" has no relations

Comment: Do you mean row number or actual ids? The solutions don't always overlap.

Comment: Missing 'category' column added

Comment: I mean row numbers

Comment: @Jester Sure then what are the key(s) of `table2`?

Comment: @Nae I've updated the tables to match my project and marked primary keys with 'PK'

Comment: How exactly is the "ducks" 3rd row? Also are you certain that you're updating the table2 arbitrarily (based on row number when ordered in certain manner, which is unknown as well)?

Comment: @Nae Sorry, English isn't my native language and I was tired when I was writing that. It's now fixed. 
And I've now added what I need the result to be. I need to populate team1 & team2 columns with teamnames from 'tname'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should match every combination and put it in the game order:

```
UPDATE games g
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        (@cnt := @cnt + 1) game_id, t.team1, t.team2
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT t1.tname team1, t2.tname team2
        FROM teams t1
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tname FROM teams) t2
        WHERE t1.tname <> t2.tname
        ) t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) c
    ) mt ON mt.game_id = g.game_id
SET g.team1 = mt.team1,
    g.team2 = mt.team2
;
```

though I'd recommend using team ids instead of team names.

---

If you mean ids then:

```
UPDATE table2 ti
SET ti.item2 = (SELECT t1.item FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = 3)
WHERE ti.id = 1
;
```